# NextJS router push with scroll to a component on another page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

suppose I'm on Page1 and a button that makes a router.push to Page2, but I need that when Page2 loads, it automatically scrolls to a component that is on Page2, but I don't know how it could be done or even if it is possible . Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect with a hash in the url:

```
router.push('mypage#myel');
```

This will then scroll to an element with the ID of `myel`.

```
<div id='myel'></div>
```

You can find more here: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/

Comment: wow! I didn't think it would be so easy, thank you very much!!